# Python Selenium: How do I click a link in a drop down menu with css selector?

Tags: python, css, selenium

The HTML looks like this:

```
<span class="MenuIcons searchButton"></span>
    ... (some stuff)
    <a data-bind="" url="/ParagonLS/Search/Property.mvc/Index/1" tabdescription="RESIDENTIAL" subtabdescription="Criteria" subtabmaxallowed="3" targetex="" rel="" class=" SearchByClass1 " subtabgroup="true" subtabgroupadd="true" subtabstartindex="0" fullwindow="False" hideaddressbar="False">TEXT</a>
```

I can get to the span using:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".MenuIcons.searchButton")
```

But since the span is a drop down menu I need to get to the inner  element, but don't know how since it has spaces around its class name. What do I do?

Comment: I tried using xpath but since the spaces are in the class names I get errors. If you can show me how to deal with the spaces then, it is a possible solution.

Comment: can you select by `link_text` ?

Comment: I could, but I need to find a way to get it unhidden. Interacting with the website you do that by clicking the <span> element, then the drop down menu appears allowing the <a> element to be clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import time
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".MenuIcons.searchButton").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("TEXT").click()
```

You can do this and click the link.

Comment: I get "Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"TEXT"}" error

Comment: @PythonNoob what is the `link text` exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I think this is much cleaner

Comment: @Saifur i guess he missed the click action before.I missed that too :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `xpath` instead since the `class` contains space.

```
//a[contains(@class,'SearchByClass1')]
```

Text based search is also another possibility.

```
//a[.='TEXT']
```

**Edit**
Executing `javascript` since the element is hidden as per OP's comment

```
test = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector(\"a[class*='SearchByClass1']\").innerHTML;");
print(test)
```

print

> TEXT

Comment: Will this work with the <a> attribute originally being hidden?

Comment: don't think so. Is that hidden?

Comment: It is hidden under the <span> element. That is why I am trying to open it first, then the <a>

Comment: Can you execute `javascript`?

Comment: I'd prefer to use Python since I am not familiar with javascript.

Comment: I can write you `javascript` you need to plug that in `python`

Comment: But there has to be a way to do it with python too. I want to be able to learn how.

Comment: I added the script, but nothing happens.

Comment: You have to do a print or something else. See my edit

Comment: It printed, but when I take away the print and add .click() it gives an error "no attribute click"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71547/discussion-between-saifur-and-python-noob).

Comment: Thanx for the chat initiative :)